# How to get option on MacOS if a socket is set to listen?

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, googletest

I use a simple googletest how to get if a socket is set to listen. There is an option on socket level `SO_ACCEPTCONN` that shows that the socket had a listen() call.

```
TEST(SocketTestSuite, check_listen) {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ASSERT_NE(sockfd, INVALID_SOCKET);

    int so_option = 987654321;
    socklen_t optlen{sizeof(so_option)};
    int ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &so_option, &optlen);

    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("Error getsockopt");
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(so_option, 0);
}
```

On Linux I get the result as expected: the socket isn't set to listen.

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite
[ RUN      ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen
[       OK ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

But on MacOS I get:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite
[ RUN      ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen
Error getsockopt: Protocol not available
/Users/runner/work/client-server-tcp/client-server-tcp/test_client-server-tcp.cpp:165: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  so_option
Which is: 987654321
  0

[  FAILED  ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen
```

Why does it complain **"Protocol not available"**? What protocol? `SO_ACCEPTCONN` is a socket option. Whatever, if I use the TCP protocol number 6 with:

```
int ret = getsockopt(sockfd, 6, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &so_option, &optlen);
```

I get this result:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite
[ RUN      ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen
/Users/runner/work/client-server-tcp/client-server-tcp/test_client-server-tcp.cpp:164: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  so_option
    Which is: 1024
  0

[  FAILED  ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from SocketTestSuite (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] SocketTestSuite.check_listen
```

MacOS is now satisfied with its protocol but it shows `so_option = 1024` that is **true** as option != 0. And that is wrong. The socket isn't set to listen. 1024 is 0x400 that looks like a bit-set option but I don't know why this is given.

What is going on here? Why MacOS does not work as expected like Linux?

Reference:
[Mac OS X standard socket.h file](https://gist.github.com/cyberroadie/3490843) 
[getsockopt() — Get the options associated with a socket](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-getsockopt-get-options-associated-socket)

Comment: Unrelated: You shouldn't really do `if (ret != 0) { perror("Error getsockopt");  } EXPECT_EQ(so_option, 0);` since the `EXPECT_EQ` output is only confusing after the failed `getsockopt` call.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right, `if (ret != 0) ...` isn't really "testing like". But my intention is first to show the issue and not a real test; here a simple way to show what `errno` returned. *"I can't replicate ... on my Linux"* Yes, you can't. There is no problem on Linux as shown in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Protocol not available" is the textual error message for `ENOPROTOOPT`, which is what `errno` reports when you try to use a `(get|set)sockopt()` option that is "unknown at the level indicated".

In other words, this means that MacOS is telling you that it does not recognize the `SO_ACCEPTCONN` option at the `SOL_SOCKET` level.  Which makes sense, because `SO_ACCEPTCONN` is not a supported option according to Apple's OSX documentation (and confirmed by various online sources) for [`getsockopt()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getsockopt.2.html) and [`setsockopt()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setsockopt.2.html).

`SO_ACCEPTCONN` has a numeric value of `2`.  By setting the level to `6` (`IPPROTO_TCP`) instead, you are asking `getsockopt()` for TCP option 2, which is `TCP_MAXSEG` (The maximum segment size for outgoing TCP packets).

So, you need to adjust your test accordingly:

```
TEST(SocketTestSuite, check_listen) {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ASSERT_NE(sockfd, INVALID_SOCKET);

    int so_option = 0;
    socklen_t optlen = sizeof(so_option);

    int ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &so_option, &optlen);
    if (ret < 0) {
        if (errno != ENOPROTOOPT)
            FAIL() << "Error getsockopt: " << strerror(errno);
        else
            FAIL() << "Option not supported by getsockopt";
    }
    else {
        EXPECT_EQ(so_option, 0);
    }

    close(sockfd);
}
```

AFAIK, there is no other `getsockopt()` option to replace `SO_ACCEPTCONN`. The only way I know to test whether a socket is listening is to use [`accept()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/accept.2.html), which will fail with `EINVAL` if it is called on a socket that is not listening.

Comment: Hm, seems I have to manage it by myself with setting a flag when calling listen(). Thank you :-)